# Warning when referencing numpy scalar types

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, documentation, python-sphinx

Sphinx emits a warning when processing the following code in nitpicky mode:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def func(x: npt.NDArray[np.double]) -> None:
    """My func docstring."""
```

The warning says

> py:class reference target not found: numpy.float64

Sphinx emits a similar warning for every scalar type.

However, there are references for each scalar type in numpy's objects.inv, for example,:

> numpy.double py:class 1 reference/arrays.scalars.html#$ -

> numpy.float64 py:attribute 1 reference/arrays.scalars.html#$ -

One notable thing is that even though I reference `np.double`, sphinx looks for `np.float64`. And as per the warning, it looks for a class, but the object is an attribute. That might be the reason, why sphinx cannot find the reference.

Given this is indeed the reason for the warning, I have to either force sphinx to search for the class that I actually reference, or tell it somehow to look for attributes, instead of classes in this particular case.

Does anyone how how to do that?

Check out this [example repo](https://github.com/Teagum/sphinx-warning) to reproduce the warning.

Comment: This seems related: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/10974.